# communication between different applications

Tags: communication, messaging

I have several applications in the system which are written in different languages. Is there a good practice to send messages between these applications?

Since applications are written in different languages, JMS is not an option. Currently, I have some ideas, such as MQ, web services, ESB service.

Is ESB the best practice?

Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

**EDIT**
Some applications are very time-consuming, so RPC call(at least blocking RPC is not really good), maybe this also needs to be taken into account.

Comment: You should consider [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: Actually I am using Rabbit MQ as a temporary solution now, but not sure if this is the best solution when more concurrent requests occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a serious look at ZeroMQ and Google Protocol Buffers. Both are well supported by a wide array of languages on many platforms.

ZeroMQ is an excellent way to move bytes between applications or threads running either on the same computer or across a network.

Google Protocol Buffers is an excellent way to make those bytes mean something to every application or thread without having to write a ton of code yourself. It's binary too, so the transmitted data is conveniently small.

So it would be pretty trivial to have, say, one program written in C++ running on Linux on an ARM CPU talking to another running in Java on Windows.

If best practice mean not having to set up an extra service or server, then these two are what you'll be wanting.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your approach is to use Google Protocol Buffer to serialize data and then use ZeroMQ to send messages, am I right? If so, what is benefit of using GPB over JSON and ZeroMQ over other MQ?